# What are the object requirements (limitations) for storing an object in RavenDB

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb, key-value-store

I am researching RavenDB for use in a system (mostly as a persistant key-value cache) and need to know what are the limitations of the actual data that can be stored.

[The documentation states](http://ravendb.net/tutorials/hello-world) "The only requirement is that a root entity string Id property" however all the samples and tutorials I am seeing only store simple string, int, decimal, bool data types.

Is it possible to store this object?

```
public class StorableObject {
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public object ValueObject {get;set;}
}
```

Using this (sudo) code?

```
// I just copy and pasted this from a random blog post -- an example to show a complex object with a lot of hierarchy, methods, properties, etc.
string boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://twitpic.com/api/uploadAndPost")
    as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = string.Format("multipart/form-data; boundary={0}", boundary);
request.PreAuthenticate = true;

var objectToStore = new StorableObject { ValueObject = request }; 
session.Store(objectToStore);
session.SaveChanges();
```

And get it back out like this:

```
var storedObject = session.Load<StorableObject>("objects/123456789");
var request = (HttpWebRequest) storedObject.ValueObject;
```

Thanks for your feedback, please excuse my contrived example, it was the easiest way I could describe what I am trying to do without delving into a bunch of domain knowledge/models.

Kyle

Comment: RavenDB can be used as a key/value store. But its value is knowing what type you've stored to pull back. 'Object' isn't helpful, but still possible. Also note that if the value is huge - as in megabytes, its best to use the Attachments API : http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/attachments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects in Raven are stored as JSON and are serialised using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). So as long as that can serialise your type it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

RavenDB can be used as a key/value store.

But its value is knowing what type you've stored to pull back. 'Object' isn't helpful, but still possible.

Also note that if the value is huge - as in megabytes, its best to use the Attachments API : http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/attachments